# how to make sublime text 3 show full keyword name instead of part of name and 3 dots

Tags: sublimetext3

How can make sublimetext3 show full keyword name instead of part of the keyword which ending with 3 dots?

For example, typing 'return' keyword it only shows 'retu...'

[image: See example]

[image]

Comment: try upgrading to the latest dev build where this was fixed or set `ui_scale` and/or `dpi_scale` in your user preferences

Comment: still see the same

Answer (score 0):

I've changed "font_size": 9 and it helped in my case.